# BCI project using EEG signals

Tags: signal-analysis, eeg

I want to make a [BCI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brain%E2%80%93computer_interface) project, based on EEG signals, to control a robot using the brain's [P300 wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P300_%28neuroscience%29).  I have read a lot of papers, which give me a wide knowledge on how to deal with those signals, but I get confused, there are many approaches that papers follow which is DSP, statistical and AI approach (usually AI approach combined with one of the first two approaches).

So, what is your advice and suggestions about what approach to follow?  (advice from senior to junior :)).

Comment: This is very broad.  Can you ask a more specific question?  What do you want to do with the BCI?

Comment: @endolith , to control a movement of robot through P300 signal

Answer (score 0):

Like @endolith said, can you be more specific what you need? and what your robot do? You can work for example with evoked potential, if you want your robot to walk and turn, you can send some visual stimulus and detect that p300 signal, only when the user are ready for that stimulus. So in p300 thats a very simple way. If there is a high-commands, for example show in a screen kitchen, bathroom, living room, and you can detect that p300 and program your robot to follow that path with Computer Vision or other techniques.